# Testrail: Can I use the test run configuration values within a test case so that they are available within the test execution?

Tags: configuration, testcase, testrail

In current TestRail v8.0.1 Default (1030) I use configurations a lot during test run definition.
It would be great to have these values (often more than one) available during test execution.

I tried to find out anything with Dr. google, however to no avail. There has been a user forum for testrail, if I remember correctly. However date of now, this seems to be gone. At least I did not find it.

My idea to my problem is to have kind of variables during test case definition that get expanded during test execution with the variable being replaced by the configuration value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TestRail, test data management through variables is possible, particularly when using a data-driven approach. However, it's important to note that this functionality is exclusively accessible in the enterprise version of the software. It's crucial to distinguish this from the concept of configurations, which serves a distinct purpose. Using configurations as data sets and employing variables for them is not considered a best practice.

In summary, there isn't a straightforward method to accomplish the problem stated by you.

Comment: Even if it does not solve my problem, I appreciate your comment anyway. 
I already was afraid that something like this would show up :-)